# Parse remote APIs (JSON and XML) using Rails 3

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-3

I am coding an app that is will be fetching data from different sources around the Internet via their respective API (JSON and XML).

How can I fetch this data (from remote source) and parse it using Rails 3?
I looked everywhere on the net for a solution but it all seems very confusing too me.

Do anyone know of a good, simple gem that I can use for remote APIs? It was so simple in PHP.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try something like this for JSON

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

result = JSON.parse(open("url_of_json_service").read)
```

See more abut the JSON gem here: http://flori.github.com/json/

Try something like this for XML

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

result = Nokogiri.XML(open("url_of_xml_service").read)
```

See more about Nokogiri here: https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri (there are other XML parsers)

Comment: Thank you! One more thing. How can I display the results on the front end page? I.e loop through the results in Rails 3?

Comment: Assuming the returned data is an array, then a normal ruby each loop should suffice.

Comment: It is returned as this: {"created_in":0.046152,"statuses":[40036896721608704,40036681583169536,40036632468004864,40036552943996928,40036376992944128]}

Comment: In that case you can loop over statuses (if that's what you require): e.g. result = JSON.parse(your_packet); result.statuses.each...

Comment: When I try this I get the error: undefined method `statuses' for #<Hash:0xb6d06cac>

Comment: How about XML, how can I display the results from that "query" on a page? There is no such thing as XML.parse.

Comment: I think you better read the Nokogiri documentation for that (it is a little more complex than JSON, but then so is the data format) see http://nokogiri.org/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

[Savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) is a nice gem which will do the work for SOAP based requests(XML). Check out its [documentation](http://savonrb.com/version2/client.html).

Here is a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon) for understanding better.

For JSON based requests you can check @DanSingerman answer.